# Windows and BlackBerry icon size and pixel density

Tags: android, windows, cordova, blackberry-10

I am creating a PhoneGap-based application for all platforms' mobile phones.

I am stuck up with what should be the pixel resolution of the icons for Windows Phone and BlackBerry.

I got the height and width to be used, but not the pixel density.  For example, like it is 120 pixel resolution for `mdpi` Android.

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Icon-Sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pixel density does not matter for app icons.**

This is a common misunderstanding that's unfortunately propagated by lots of graphics guys.

Smartphones will display images based on their **pixel sizes**.  A 57 pixel x 57 pixel icon will display the same way on your smartphone app, regardless of whether it's saved at 72 dpi, or 144 dpi, or anything else.

*Pixel density is useful, for example, in situations where you are printing out an image (to paper).  In that situation, the printer software will adjust the physical size of the image based on the pixel density.*

Smartphones may have a pixel density of their own screen, but this is not used to pick display sizes for images.  So, the answer is that you don't have to worry about `dpi`.

---

**Note:** users familiar with Android may be particularly confused by this issue, because of Android's resource naming conventions (`hdpi`, `ldpi`, `mdpi`, etc.).  In this case, Android will pick the images from the appropriate folder (e.g. `drawable-mdpi`) depending on the device's screen density, but the actual dpi value encoded **inside** the image file is still irrelevant.  Images in these different folders should have different *physical* pixel sizes (`mdpi` has smaller images than `hdpi`), but the images' pixel densities aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget to add this on config.xml

```
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/icon_at_2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="icons/bb/icon.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="icons/bb/icon_hover.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="icons/winphone/icon.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <!-- winphone requires a jpg for the tile icons -->
    <icon src="icons/winphone/tileicon.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" />
    <icon src="icons/webos/icon.png" gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="icons/webos/miniicon.png" gap:platform="webos" gap:role="mini" />

    <!-- Splash Screens -->
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/bb/splash.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/winphone/splash.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
```

### Windows Phone::

Home Screen

```
62px, small application tile
173px, large application tile
48px, application bar icons
```

Windows Phone Marketplace

```
99px, small mobile app icon
173px, large mobile app icon
200px, PC app title icon
480x800px, details page screenshot
1000x800px, panorama background
480x800px, application splash screen
```

### BlackBerry::

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17965/Dimensions_for_indicators_1155197_11.jsp

> tablet webworks: 90px
>
> BB10: 114px
>
> BlackBerry 6: "For application icons, create an icon file that does not exceed 68-by-68 pixels. This size includes the canvas. Keep
>   the weight of icons inside a 49-by-49 pixels space. Smaller elements
>   can extend beyond this size but icons should not exceed 55-by-55
>   pixels. If the icon within the canvas exceeds this size, it could be
>   scaled down and upset the line weights and gradients."

Comment: Hey Amit I have done this for icons , and I have gone through the link but everywhere its mentioning the height and width only ,but not the pixel density of the icons for the specific platform. Like its 330 dpi for Iphone so how it goes for windows and BB. Please help me out